# Angular 6 - Unsubscribe from a Pipe

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

I have two components on the same route that talk with one service. They are separated by tabs that each keep them in their own view.

Within the two components I have the same code:

Component A:

```
this.view = this._dataService.pipe(map((resp: any) => {
    return (<DataResult>{
        console.log("Grabbing data for Component A");
        data: resp.Data
    });
}));
```

Component B:

```
this.view = this._dataService.pipe(map((resp: any) => {
    return (<DataResult>{
        console.log("Grabbing data for Component B");
        data: resp.Data
    });
}));
```

The problem is when I switch tabs or views the pipe is called even though the view is different. Going on Component B will console log "Grabbing data for Component A" and vice versa.

**How can I shut off the pipe?** When the tab is changed?

Comment: My suggestion would be to make it where only one component is "alive" at a time, therefore only one subscription is active at any given point.

Comment: You could add to a Subscription, that way you unsubscribe when you want.

Comment: @maury844 How can you check what component is 'alive'?

Comment: In the NgDestroy hook for each component, You can unsubscribe to the Subscription Or you can use `untilDestroyed` from `ngx-take-until-destroy` to unsubscribe

Comment: could you not just do the individual maps in the different components? If that would add too much duplication, have a look at `shareReplay`. It might be what you're looking for. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

Comment: @SadCRUDDeveloper you can add a ```console.log``` on the ```onInit``` for both your component's and see if both of them log "at the same time", my suggestion would be that if ```ComponentA``` is showing, ```ComponentB``` should not be instantiated at that time, so you can hook your ```subscribe``` and ```unsubscribe``` to the Angular's lifecycle hooks for the component

Comment: if you need to get only once you can use take(1) in both of component in pipe after map method

Answer (score 0):

You can add variable to the service and use it to save the state of the components like that:

```
stateParam; // can put it on the service or in the component and change it once tab was clicked

this._dataService.pipe(
filter(a => stateParam == "componentB"), 
map((resp: any) => {
    return (<DataResult>{
        console.log("Grabbing data for Component B");
        data: resp.Data
    });
}));
```